# Issue with making loops, as well as returning to beginning

Tags: c

C

```
int main() {
    
    int a[10],min,max,sum,length,n,input,i,search, elementfound;
    float avg;
    int quit = -1;
    
    printf("=== Enter the number of elements (1-10) : " );
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>10 || n<1) {
        printf("Enter size of array: ");
        if(n>10) {
            printf("/n=Enter size of array: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
        }
        else{
        
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
}
    
    
    printf("Enter elements of array: ");
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    min=a[0];
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(min>a[i])
            min=a[i];
            if(max<a[i])
                max=a[i];
    } 

    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }
    
    avg=(float)sum/n;
    
    

    printf("Sequence length: %d\n", n);
    printf("Sequence min: %d\n", min);
    printf("Sequence max: %d\n", max);
    printf("Sequence average: %.2f\n", avg);
        
    printf("Enter an integer to search, -1 to stop: ");
    scanf("%d",&search);
    
    while(search!=-1) {
    
    elementfound = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]==search)
        {
            elementfound=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(elementfound==1){
        printf("\n%d was found in array at position %d.", search, i+1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d was not found in array.", search);
    }
    return 0;
}

printf("Thank you see you next time.");
    
}
```

I want it so that the user has to enter a number between 1-10 to proceed
right now any number you enter takes you to the printf("Enter size of array: ");
step
I also want it to loop itself back to the beginning of the game when a user searches for a number within the array
currently exists after checking once
when there is a type -1 to exit option
ive been stuck on this for like a couple hrs
it'd be so nice if someone could help me as I am new to coding

Comment: add a space before the percentage sign in scanf:
```scanf(" %d", &n);```

Comment: @Maaddy If you have an answer, please put it in the answer section where it can be properly peer reviewed. Thanks.

Comment: @Maaddy there is no need to add a space before the `"%d"` conversion specifier, all conversion specifiers EXCEPT `"%c"` and `"%[..]"` ignore leading whitespace (and for chux `"%n"` likewise does not ignore leading whitespace)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know, but this weird error happened to me many times before where everything is okay but scanf doesn't work properly, unless I add an additional whitespace before the specifier !

Comment: Yes, there are no adverse effects from including a whitespace -- but there really isn't anything weird that happens in programming -- there is always a concise reason (even when that ends up being a rare, purple-elephant type, compiler error...)